# How to load defuns automatically at repl start up?

Tags: repl, scheme

I'm working through SICP and I'm getting tired of defining the square function for the thousandth time, so I'd like to load it (and some others) automatically when I start the repl.

I use Geiser, but if you know how this works in any other REPL I'd switch.

(Of course there would have to be a way to start the repl without autoloading anything, in case one sets it up to autoload an infinite loop by mistake. But I usually only get these when I try to use a function, not when I define it.)

Comment: This is not an Emacs question, but rather a Guile (or Racket) question, I think.  Geiser is only used to talk to the REPL process.  You can load up a file containing your definitions with `(load "filename")` in Guile.

Comment: Look at `geiser-repl-history-filename`, setting this variable will make Geiser store the history of your work with the REPL. Also, you could simply load files with stored code using `,geiser-load-file` in REPL. Try `,help geiser-load-file` for some more info.